# ssh: Cannot resolve *ANY* hostname: “Could not resolve hostname x Name or service not known”

Tags: ssh

ssh cannot resolve any hostnames, at all, but connects fine when an IP is used. nslookup works fine. ping works fine. All other web utilities work fine. There is some strange configuration issue with ssh.

The answer should not be to define any custom hosts in a config file since this problem is not limited to custom hosts that I've created. It happens on any and all domains.

I'm using Windows 10 and Cygwin. PuTTy works fine too btw.

I looked at similar questions but none had my specific issue, and most were about issues resolving domains on custom networks. Any idea what the issue may be?

Comment: It sounds like a DNS issue, from a command prompt can you: nslookup one of those hostnames?

Comment: yes. I mentioned that nslookup works fine.

Comment: nslookup might be using old lookups.  Try restarting your DNS client in your services.msc.  I also think nslookup uses something else to resolve, while most everything else uses the DNS Client Service.

Comment: What about ping and git? They both successfully resolve hostnames while ssh doesn't. I'm thinking it has to be some random configuration setting in ssh